# How to check if a directory contains a certain file type?

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to make a program that goes through each file in a folder, processing any text files found. 
So far I have something like this:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        open(file)
```

How can I get it to return an error if no text files exist in the directory?

Comment: easy with Unix command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to check the count of `.txt` files is `0` then you could use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html?highlight=glob%20glob#glob.glob) instead:

```
import glob

if len(glob.glob("*.txt")) == 0:
    print "No TXT files"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob

if not glob.glob("*.txt"):
  print('No text files Found')
```